# Can't find MIT/GNU Scheme in Applications after install

Tags: macos, terminal

I installed program called "MIT/GNU Scheme" to /Applications. I can run it via Spotlight, but it says it's from unidentified developer. So I should find it in the folder and right click open, but it's not in the folder. Terminal autocomplete cannot find it either. If I install it again, it says it is there and asks whether to replace the old file. Read somewhere it might be 32bit version on my 64bit system, but I specifically installed 64bit version. I am running OS X 10.10.4

Comment: Where did you get it from?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme 
md5 is correct

Comment: Is there anything beginning MIT in your /Applications folder - The documentation is appalling for OS X and should be reported as a major bug. This question on SO suggesting macports or homebrew which is usually the best way for a command line Unix program where the developers don't seem to know OS X

Comment: How did you install it? When I download the dmg and drag and drop the application to the `/Application` folder, I can see it in Finder, `ls /Applications` lists it, and I can run it from command line with `/Applications/MIT\:GNU\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources/mit-scheme`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can confirm where it was installed in `/Applications` by using Terminal.app:

```
cd /Applications
ls -lt | grep -i cheme
```

This should print the name of the directory where it was installed (which should be *MIT:GNU Scheme*). You can access it from the command-line by adding the following directory to your `PATH`: `/Applications/MIT\:GNU\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources`.

Comment: thank you, my problem somehow went away, not sure if it was because of your advice, but I can see the app now, so I'm closing the question

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can also visit the *Security & Privacy* panel in *System Preferences* right after trying to run the program from Spotlight. The panel should have an option to run (the last tried) program from an unidentified developer.

Comment: Yes that allows me to run the file, thank you. I'm still unable to run it from console, delete and link it, though. (Sorry if I wasn't clear in the original question)

Comment: @rdkn - you do not mention anything about console in your question - you need to edit that. Also you can't run anything from OSX's console which is a viewer of log files. Perhaps you mean Terminal?

Comment: @Mark: yes I meant Terminal, sorry